# Firestore data duplication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to setup a friend system in Firestore. My data model looks like this at the moment:

```
collection("users") -> 
  document("user1")
  document("user2")
  ...
```

A document in the `users` collection contains data like the `name`, `email`... of the user. I'd like to enable a user to have friends now, but I'm unsure about the best way to model this.
So, I'd for sure add a `friends` field in the documents of the users, but what should this field contain? My first thought was a pointer to a new collection called friends in which the documents are users. Something like this:

```
collection("users") { 
  document("user1") {
    name:user1,
    friends: -> collection("friends") {
      document("user2"),
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

This seems reasonable, but that'd mean that I'd have a lot of duplicate data in my database because each user that has friends will be duplicated in a `friends` collection. Should I worry about this or is this normal in a Firestore database structure?
Would it perhaps be possible to point to a document in the `users` collection from the `friends` collection? Something like:

```
collection("users") { 
  document("user1") {
    name:user1,
    friends: -> collection("friends") {
      document, -----
      ...            |
    }                |
  },                 |
  document("user2")<-
}
```

Or should I throw away the thought of using a collection for friends and just keep a list with uids of all friends of the user?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using two separate collections for `users` and `friends` first all you can do it by one collection. But I don't want to go there may be there was another scenario. 
As your separate collection way, you can design your `friends` collection model to meet no duplication:

`{
 name : 'Name',
 email : 'email@mail.com'
 has_connected : {
   'user1' : true // here you can use anyother unique key from user
 }
}`

The thing is that **firestore** recommend this types of design for query and for faster performance you can make that `has_connected` key as index.

In this approach, you have to check during adding new friend by email or any other unique key. if exists then just put another key into `has_connected` with the respective user. e.g `user2 : true`.

Finally, for fetching all friends for a user you have to do a query  like this: e.g: in javascript

`` let ref = firebase.firestore().collection("friends");
    ref
      .where(`has_connected.${username}`, "==", true)
      .get()
      .then(//do your logic)
      .catch() ``

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a less than optimal way of doing it. If I'm understanding what you are saying, you'd put all users in the `hasConnected` field with a boolean to check wether they are. If they are not, the key is a waste of space. I am interested in how you'd solve this with one collection. I only have a `users` collection right now. So no friend system/structure has been implemented.

Comment: its not optimal but firestore isn't relational database. yeah there is no unique feature and relation like RDBMS.

Comment: But I'm not looking for the best solution of all. I'm just looking for the best one in Firestore :) But could you elaborate more on whether data duplication would be a bad thing to do in my case and on how I'd model this using just one collection?

Comment: Basically, I recommend this way for no data duplication. I don't know any other way for firestore, I did this way in my application. If you found a better way then please share.